# how to link between j2me Client and ruby on Rails Server

Tags: java-me

I m Beginner in j2me...i hv Client Server program...Client is J2me(Mobile) and Server Ruby on Rails(Desktop)..i need upload a file(txt or xml) to server(ruby on rails) from Mobile(J2me)..please Suggest me to how to give link between J2me and ruby on Rails..

Answer (score 1):

Use the http stuff:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/HttpConnection.htm